# Larave noting save hash password in database

Tags: php, laravel

My need create new user in admin dashboard, this store function, but database saving string not hash, please help.
When I output via dd(), then the hash working

```
`
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed'
    ]);

    $object = new Specialist();
    $object->groups = 3;
    $object->password = \Hash::make($data['password']);
    $object->fill(request()->all());

    $object->save();

    return redirect()->route('specialists.index');
}
`
```

Model

```
`class Specialist extends Model
{
  // USE DATABASE TABLE users
  protected $table = 'users';

  // FILL COLUMNS...
  protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'name'];

}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$object->fill(request()->all());
```

This line is **overwriting** the password field because `request()->all()` includes `password`.

Use `except()` method to remove the fields that you don't need:

```php
 $object->password = \Hash::make($data['password']);
 $object->fill(request()->except('password'));
```